# Using 'Copy as cURL' from Chrome in windows command line

Tags: windows, curl, command-line, command

So, Google Chrome as this great 'copy as cURL' option under 'Network' of the Chrome DevTools. Works great in command lines for linux but not in windows. Apparently it has something to do with the single quotes as the error I get is

> protocol 'http not supported

In other words its reading that single quote. Is there a simple way to make this formatable for windows? I tried replacing all the single quotes with double quotes but then nothing happens at all.

The command is:

```
curl 'http://www.test.com/login/' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=7dvb25maaaaaa9d7bbbbbc3f6' -H 'Origin: http://www.test.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Host: www.test.com' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: http://www.test.com/login/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'loc=&login=user%40test.com&password=password&submit1=Sign+In' --compressed
```

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected if you use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Personally, I use the mintty terminal from cygwin which works great compared to the command prompt that comes with windows.

To create a script in cygwin:

Open cygwin terminal

- type nano file.sh
- paste (shift+insert) the curl you copied earlier, then press control+O then enter
- type chmod +x file.sh
- type bash file.sh to run the batch.

Comment: True, Cygwin does work but I need to run it in batch files which is why I want it using the standard windows command line. Unless there's a way to run a batch file in Cygwin - I'm sure there is but I don't know how.

Comment: It's possible to run a batch, I added a description of that on the response.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it was Chrome?

Because Chrome, as of v35 least, uses "double-quotes" for it's *Copy as cURL* feature.

On the other hand, Firefox uses 'single-quotes'.

If you search/replace the single-quotes for double-quotes within the entire command, it should work as expected.

e.g. you need:

`curl "http://www.test.com/login/" etc.`

Comment: Now Firefox is using double-quotes when copying so it works in Windows too without needing to search-replace.

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time trouble shooting this. What Chrome gave me didn't work in the Windows command line shell. However, if I did the "Copy as cURL" on my Mac and used that exact command on Windows it did work.